# Dynamic assembly loading vs multiple executables

Tags: c#, plugin-architecture

I have ecommerce webapplication, that can connect to multiple storage systems. Currently I am using nuget to deploy it.

I would like to split my application into parts (per storage system), because it takes long time to build and debug it (all referenced assemblies are scanned for DI). There will be only one storage system per application at time.

I made some research:
 #1. make separate webapplication per storage system (project with all packages referenced)
pros:
 - no differences between dev build and client build
 - easy to deal with native libraries (they will be copied by msbuild)
 - easy configuration and deploy
cons:
 - referencing more projects that it needs
 - multiple executables = problems with deploy, licensing etc

#2 dynamically load assembly at runtime from nuget package
pros:
 - single executable
 - can take advantage of this system to dynamically load smaller plugins (like payments etc.)
 - extensible design (in future can add additional catalogues etc. with plugin)
cons:
 - harder configuration (devops may attempt to use together invalid or outdated components)
 - problems with native libs and content files (they will be stored in separate nuget packages)
 - harder to test (devs will probably still use metaproject to test it rather than dynamic loading, so something may be screwed on prod version)

Are there other things that I need to take into account when making this decision?